# Cut out a time margin of netcdf in r

Tags: r, netcdf

I just generated a large netcdf file from WRF modeling. The file has 143 variables, 122 global attributes and 9 dimension. It covers a 7-day period with a time step of 6 hours. All I wanted to do is to cut out and discard everything for the first day (first 4 time steps) and keep the rest of files. I searched for `transNcdfCutFiles` function within the `ncdf.tools` package but was a bit confused at how to properly use it.

I am new to NetCDF processing by R. Any suggestions or help are greatly appreciated!

I could not attached the file as it is pretty large, but here is a list of the variables. Thanks in advance.

```
names(ncin$var)
  [1] "Times"                 "XLAT"                 
  [3] "XLONG"                 "LU_INDEX"             
  [5] "ZNU"                   "ZNW"                  
  [7] "ZS"                    "DZS"                  
  [9] "VAR_SSO"               "U"                    
 [11] "V"                     "W"                    
 [13] "PH"                    "PHB"                  
 [15] "T"                     "HFX_FORCE"            
 [17] "LH_FORCE"              "TSK_FORCE"            
 [19] "HFX_FORCE_TEND"        "LH_FORCE_TEND"        
 [21] "TSK_FORCE_TEND"        "MU"                   
 [23] "MUB"                   "NEST_POS"             
 [25] "P"                     "PB"                   
 [27] "FNM"                   "FNP"                  
 [29] "RDNW"                  "RDN"                  
 [31] "DNW"                   "DN"                   
 [33] "CFN"                   "CFN1"                 
 [35] "THIS_IS_AN_IDEAL_RUN"  "P_HYD"                
 [37] "Q2"                    "T2"                   
 [39] "TH2"                   "PSFC"                 
 [41] "U10"                   "V10"                  
 [43] "RDX"                   "RDY"                  
 [45] "RESM"                  "ZETATOP"              
 [47] "CF1"                   "CF2"                  
 [49] "CF3"                   "ITIMESTEP"            
 [51] "XTIME"                 "QVAPOR"               
 [53] "QCLOUD"                "QRAIN"                
 [55] "SHDMAX"                "SHDMIN"               
 [57] "SNOALB"                "TSLB"                 
 [59] "SMOIS"                 "SH2O"                 
 [61] "SMCREL"                "SEAICE"               
 [63] "XICEM"                 "SFROFF"               
 [65] "UDROFF"                "IVGTYP"               
 [67] "ISLTYP"                "VEGFRA"               
 [69] "GRDFLX"                "ACGRDFLX"             
 [71] "ACSNOM"                "SNOW"                 
 [73] "SNOWH"                 "CANWAT"               
 [75] "SSTSK"                 "COSZEN"               
 [77] "LAI"                   "VAR"                  
 [79] "MAPFAC_M"              "MAPFAC_U"             
 [81] "MAPFAC_V"              "MAPFAC_MX"            
 [83] "MAPFAC_MY"             "MAPFAC_UX"            
 [85] "MAPFAC_UY"             "MAPFAC_VX"            
 [87] "MF_VX_INV"             "MAPFAC_VY"            
 [89] "F"                     "E"                    
 [91] "SINALPHA"              "COSALPHA"             
 [93] "HGT"                   "TSK"                  
 [95] "P_TOP"                 "T00"                  
 [97] "P00"                   "TLP"                  
 [99] "TISO"                  "TLP_STRAT"            
[101] "P_STRAT"               "MAX_MSTFX"            
[103] "MAX_MSTFY"             "RAINC"                
[105] "RAINSH"                "RAINNC"               
[107] "SNOWNC"                "GRAUPELNC"            
[109] "HAILNC"                "CLDFRA"               
[111] "SWDOWN"                "GLW"                  
[113] "SWNORM"                "OLR"                  
[115] "XLAT_U"                "XLONG_U"              
[117] "XLAT_V"                "XLONG_V"              
[119] "ALBEDO"                "CLAT"                 
[121] "ALBBCK"                "EMISS"                
[123] "NOAHRES"               "TMN"                  
[125] "XLAND"                 "UST"                  
[127] "PBLH"                  "HFX"                  
[129] "QFX"                   "LH"                   
[131] "ACHFX"                 "ACLHF"                
[133] "SNOWC"                 "SR"                   
[135] "SAVE_TOPO_FROM_REAL"   "HFX_FDDA"             
[137] "ISEEDARR_RAND_PERTURB" "ISEEDARR_SPPT"        
[139] "ISEEDARR_SKEBS"        "LANDMASK"             
[141] "LAKEMASK"              "SST"                  
[143] "SST_INPUT"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to do from the command line using cdo :

```
cdo seltimestep,5/nsteps ifile ofile
```

where nsteps is the number of timesteps in the file.